# Django Subdomains - Web page has a redirect loop

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am developing this django app for users that I intend each user to have their own custom subdomain. I intend to use a middleware for this purpose. So far, this is what I got, but on accessing the site (on Google chrome), I get the redirect loop error:

```
class SubdomainMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.company is None:
                company_subdomain = request.user.company.company_url
            else:
                company_subdomain = request.company.company_url
            company_subdomain = company_subdomain.lower()
            domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
            if len(domain_parts) > 2:
                if domain_parts[0].lower() != company_subdomain:
                    domain_parts[0] = company_subdomain
            else:
                domain_parts.insert(0, company_subdomain)
            domain = '.'.join(domain_parts)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://' + domain + request.get_full_path())
        else:
            pass
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first redirect is correct, but then you redirect again even though you are on the right domain. This results in the redirect loop. You need to check if the current subdomain matches the intended subdomain, and if it does, return `None` instead of a redirect:

```
if len(domain_parts) > 2:
    if domain_parts[0].lower() != company_subdomain:
        domain_parts[0] = company_subdomain
    else:  # Subdomain matches, return instead of redirect
        return None
else:
    domain_parts.insert(0, company_subdomain)
```

Comment: Makes sense but still doesn't do it. Still get this >>> This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: Sorry, this works. Another problem was the line where I redirect. I was using http instead of https. Thanks.

Comment: And lastly, how would you handle the last bit if a user is not authenticated, as now here there should be no subdomain?